# How can I operate on more Emacs buffers at the same time?

Tags: vim, emacs, buffer

I am looking for an equivalent of the `:bufdo` Vim command in Emacs. `:bufdo` takes an argument - another command - and executes the command on all open buffers. I have not yet found a similar feature in Emacs.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on what your command is, you can do:

```
M-: (mapc (lambda (b) (set-buffer b) (*command*)) (buffer-list))
```

But, I have a feeling you want something not so lispy.  Take a look at [keyboard macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html).  Namely, decide what you want to do:

```
C-x ( <do-your-command> C-x )
M-: (mapc (lambda (b) (set-buffer b) (kmacro-end-and-call-macro)) (buffer-list))
```

You'd probably want to define that last part as a function if you use it much:

```
(defun bufdo ()
   "execute last macro on all buffers, ala bufdo from vi"
   (interactive)
   (mapc (lambda (b) 
            (with-current-buffer b
              (kmacro-end-and-call-macro)))
         (buffer-list)))
```

Note: code is untested

Comment: Probably best to use "with-current-buffer", like (loop for buf in (buffer-list) do (with-current-buffer buf <forms>)).

Answer (score 6):

You can also checkout [ibuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode), it allows you to mark buffers you like to operate on with `m` and then you can execute something on it with `E`. Other common operations are also available, e.g. `query-replace` on `Q`. Just check out the menu or the mode description (`C-h m`).

BTW, similar things are also possible from [dired](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredMode), although it doesn't seem to give you an `eval` command.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at buffer-list (function).  It returns a list of all the open buffers (BUFFER objects).  See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/The-Buffer-List.html) for a simple example of using it with mapcar (which operates on every element of the list, and accumulates the results).  You would probably also find set-buffer, which programatically sets the current buffer from Emacs Lisp, useful.